# Store a reactiveVal on session exit

Tags: r, shiny

In a server function with a `reactiveVal`, how can I write the value to local storage when the session disconnects?

For a non-reactive val, say `x`, I would do:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    save(x, file = filename)
    stopApp()
})
```

But if I'd earlier had `x <- reactiveVal(x)`, then my guess at

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    save(x(), file = filename)
    stopApp()
})
```

fails. Apparently, "[I] tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer."

**update with mwe**

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

    msg1 <- 'Works fine.'
    msg2 <- reactiveVal('No worky.')

    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        save(msg1, file = 'msg1.RData')
        msg <- msg2()
        save(msg, file = 'msg2.RData')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(), server = server)
```

Comment: Are there multiple users in your app at once? If not, you could store the reactiveVal as a global variable.

Comment: Single user, but I don't understand your solution. Can you modify my example to demonstrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that works fine if there is only one user in an active process. We write the `reactiveVal` to the global environment any time it changes using the `<<-` operator. When the session ends, we write that global variable to a file.

This is also why it goes wrong if multiple users are in the same Shiny process simultaneously; they share the global environment. So if the sequence is: User 1 modifies, user 2 modifies, user 1 exits, user 2 exits, with this implementation we write the `reactiveVal` from user 2 to disk twice.

Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  msg1 <- 'Works fine.'
  msg2 <- reactiveVal('No worky.')

  observeEvent(msg2(),
               {
                msg <<- msg2() # Write to global environment 
               })

  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    # Write from global environment to file
    save(msg, file = 'msg.RData')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(), server = server)
```